# How to attach an access token to http request by browser using blazor webassembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor web assembly with a rest api.
The api is secured, so i have to pass an access token with the request.

Program.cs

```
services.AddHttpClient("api")
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

in the components I inject IHttpClientFactory, and create a http client using

```
var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("api")
```

When I use the client created above, the token is attached to the request and the request is successful.

How can i attach the access token when the browser makes the http request due to elements such as img.
Ex. I have a component

```
<div >
   <img class="card-image" src="api/products/1/thumbnail">
</div>
```

When this request is made, no token is attached so the request returns a 401.
I tried using http client to download the image, then transfer it to javascript via interop and setting the image, but it very slow compared to letting the browser download.

Adding more code

Page Component
There is a div acting as a wrap panel around virtualize.

```
<Virtualize Items="@Products" >
    <ChildContent>

        <TestProductView Product="@context" HttpClient="@GetClient()" />

    </ChildContent>
</Virtualize>
```

TestProductView.razor

```
<div style="height:320px;width:300px;padding:8px;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:15px; ">
  <img height='220' width="170" class="card-image" src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData)">
</div>
```

TestProductView.razor.cs

```
 public partial class TestProductView : ComponentBase
{


    [Parameter]
    public ProductMedia Product { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }

    byte[] ImageData;
    bool ImageLoaded = false;

    static int LoadCount;
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {            
        if (!ImageLoaded)
        {
            ImageData = Array.Empty<byte>();
            var c = Interlocked.Increment(ref LoadCount);

            if (Product.HasLink(StoreApiLinks.Product.Thumbnail, HttpMethod.Get) == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var url = Product.GetUrl(StoreApiLinks.Product.Thumbnail, HttpMethod.Get);
                    var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(url);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        ImageData = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    }
                    
                    ImageLoaded = true;
                }
                catch
                {

                }

            }
            
        }

        await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }        

}
```

For this sample i load 50 products to the page.
When i scroll up and down, i can see the request (25) for the thumbnails going out. The scrolling is also laggy.

Thanks,

Mathi

Comment: did you try  `<img src="data:image/png;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes))" ` ? Make API call from component and just convert image bytes to base64 string and set it directly in the html.

Comment: Yes, when i tried that it didn't perform well. I will try again.

Comment: what is the image size? how many images page is trying to load? Conversion is slow or image rendering is causing slowness?

Comment: Average image size is about 75KB. I'm using Virtualize to only show 12 images at a time out of 2500. On scroll the images are converted again even though it is still visible.

Comment: 75KB shouldn't take much time. Can you post the exact code and what you are trying to do?